# Restore Windows Installation

Tags: system-installation, windows, bootloader

I've got the following problem: I had a ssd (sda) with windows 8 installed. Now I added another ssd (sdb) and installed ubuntu 14.10 on it, but I didn't create a efi partition and installed to sda.
So after the installation completed, I could only start ubuntu.
After that I tried to reinstall ubuntu with the boot manager installed to an efi partition on sdb, but this failed and now i can't boot in any system.

So my question is, how can I restore the windows installation/bootloader.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. Burn this to a CD or USB drive: http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/.
2. Boot from that disk and run Boot Repair to get Ubuntu working again.
3. Once you boot into Ubuntu, open a terminal and run `sudo update-grub`. This should add the Windows bootloader to the GRUB menu and you can then reboot into GRUB and select Windows.